# Problem in migrating my Django db from sqlite to mysql

Tags: mysql, django, migration

I need to migrate my db from sqlite to mysql , I refered to following article which seems to be good
https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/django-transfer-data-from-sqlite-to-another-database/
problem is data is not migrated to mysql db( but tables are created )

Can you recommend a solution

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in the article? Did you dump your data to `db.json` before switching your database settings?

Comment: Have you loaded data with loaddata command?

Comment: @lainShelvington Yes

Comment: @TrueGopnik Yes

Comment: @user123 does `db.json` contain all the data you expect?

Comment: @lainShelvington Yes

Comment: @user123 you're certain that the `python manage.py loaddata db.json` command runs successfully after your database settings are pointing to MySQL? You don't get an error? If there is no error then I'm not sure how anyone could help, the docs do suggest that there may be issues if you use the MyISAM storage engine